# Please explain this Python3 line to me from the 'drunks' function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was helped with this line but don't understand it completely. Any insight would be amazing!

```
def drunks(bottle, end):

        print(bottle or 'No more','bottle'+('s' if bottle-1 else ''),end)
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: for example, what is 'bottle' for? it states "bottle or 'No More'"

Comment: im having a hard time understanding how it pieces the information together. i can post the entire code if youd like.

Comment: Examine the output of `drunks(0, "\n")`, `drunks(1, "\n")`, and `drunks(2, "\n")`, and see if you can figure out why it outputs what it does.

Comment: okay will do!!!

Comment: Consider `bottle or 'No more'` separately from `'bottle'+('s' if bottle-1 else '')` as they are separate arguments to `print()`.  The key to understanding what's going on is that `0` evaluates to `True` and non-zero evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def drunks(bottle, end):
    print(bottle or 'No more', 'bottle' + ('s' if bottle - 1 else ''), end)
```

Explanation:

- Your function `drunks()` takes 2 arguments (`bottle` and `end`).
- The built-in `print()` function takes unlimited number of positional arguments (in your case, they are **3**).
- So it will print the three values, separated by the default delimiter (which is **a space**).
- First expression (`bottle or 'No more'`):

  - Python supports [**short-circuit evaluation**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). See the first row of the table in the link: `x or y` | `if x is false, then y, else x`
  - So in your case `bottle or 'No more'`, if `bottle` is [**a falsy value**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), `No more` will be printed. But if `bottle` is a **truthy** one, it will be printed (I don't know what type `bottle` is, but I think it is an integer).
- Second expression (`bottle + ('s' if bottle - 1 else '')`):

  - Here, at first `bottle` is always printed.
  - Then, we append the result of `'s' if bottle - 1 else ''`. We append the letter `s` if `bottle - 1` is a **truthy** value (**not a falsy one**), otherwise we append an empty string (*which is simply nothing*).
- In the end, we print the `end` parameter, which can also be any type of value.

Answer (score 0):

When you say print bottle or '...', it's saying if bottle!=0. If you inputed 0 into this, you would get the no more bottles, if you type in 1, you'll get singular bottle as opposed to bottles. For the second if statement, you'll always write bottles unless bottle - 1 = 0 (when bottle equals 1)